# Actually move the mouse

Tags: java, mouse

I am trying to write an automation program, currently using java.awt.robot

I am trying to move the mouse, my current code is

```
robot.mouseMove((int) (MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()
    .getX() + MXv), (int) MouseInfo
    .getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY());
```

for x and

```
robot.mouseMove((int) MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()
    .getX(), (int) (MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()
    .getY() + MYv));
```

for y. By reading the mouse position with MouseInfo and slightly changing it. It works fine for normal mouse motion, but for example minecraft doesn't do anything (normally moving your mouse rotates the character).

I believe it is because it needs actual motion, not just "teleporting" the mouse. How can I fix that?

Thank you

EDIT:

MXv is my X-Axis motion

MYv my Y-Axis

and robot is a java.awt.robot instance

and I know I can do both in one command, but I need it like this

Comment: Mouse "motion" is just a series of "small teleportations".

Comment: but how do I get games to accept it then, is there another library alternative?

Comment: Instead of doing `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()
    .getX() + MXv`, loop over `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()
    .getX() + MXv/10` for example